# <sonar.exclusions> in pom.xml (Maven multi-module project) works locally but not on company server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm using `<sonar.exclusions>` in pom.xml to exclude certain packages for unit test code coverage. I have set up Sonar locally and the exclusions reflect on the report. But then, the same exclusions are not honored on the company server.

I am using `<sonar.skippedModules>` which works as intended and skips the required modules perfectly fine on both environments.

Local Sonar version is Version 4.3.1 Company's Sonar version is Version 4.1.2

An example of how I have written `<sonar.skippedModules>` in one of the modules:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.mainClass>.....</project.mainClass>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        /src/main/java/../../../../../Package1/*,
        /src/main/java/../../../../../Package2/*,
        /src/main/java/../../../../../JavaClass1.java
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties>
```

Can you please help me understand why [`<sonar.exclusions>`](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles) is honored only locally but not when I build the job (set up on Jenkins) to generate the Sonar report on the company server? Does the difference in the version matter?

Would absence of new-line character following the comma to separate the package names make a difference?

Comment: Why do you use '../..'? Do you want exclude all file in Package1, Package2 and class JavaClass1 in all package?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this, I had same issue and it worked for me

Don't start with "`/src/main/java/`"
Instead start with "`com/companyname/projectname/`"

I personally prefer "`**com/companyname/projectname/../**`"

Comment: It looks like `sonar.exclusions` doesn't exclude the multiple paths like `**/enums/**,**/entity/**,**/constant/**`

Answer (score 4):

I might be mistaken, but you should remove the `/` characters at the beginning of the `sonar.exclusions` pathes, to have them computed relative to the project's root directory.

Comment: It looks like `sonar.exclusions` doesn't exclude the multiple paths like `**/enums/**,**/entity/**,**/constant/**`